# Updating a secondary list with the values from a primary list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I've got List A and List B. I'm using SharePoint Online and Power Automate

When an item is List A I want Flow to copy the item to List B. I'm adding some additional fields which will be mandatory for the next stage.

I'm using a Get Items action to get the values from List A, then I have an Apply to each loop with value as the output. This is followed by a Update item action which I'm pointing at List B and using the values returned from the Get Items action to update the fields.

This is part of a larger flow (should I create it as it's own separate Flow?). I'm checking the results from  the Update item action and it seems to be showing the item values in the Id and Body fields but on the output I'm getting a 404. I've haven't recreated all the fields from List A to list B yet as I wanted to run a proof of concept test.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the item doesn't exist in List B, you should use create item action to copy the item, or if the item already exists, then you could use update item action.

Please refer below article to copy items between two data sources:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467880/how-to-copy-items-between-two-sharepoint-lists-by-using-flow